# how to connect laravel api auth for mobile android

Tags: android, laravel

how to connect Laravel as a Web Service to Android. im running laravel on localhost and try to connect with device through wifi connection.

```
 final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "succes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            set_user_data();
                        }
                    },500);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                    showProgress(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("apikey", getResources().getString(R.string.pasarku_app_key));
                    Log.i("key",getResources().getString(R.string.pasarku_app_key));
                    return headers;

                }
```

i got error on android monitor when sign up

[error when try to signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E50M.png)

Comment: error 401 tells problem with Authentication.. check weather your api works on postman too ?. more about [error 401](https://httpstatuses.com/401)

Comment: using postman didnt works either but i found the solution here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290876/trying-to-send-android-volley-post-request-to-laravel)